# Comparing columns of 2 dataframes and cutting missmatching rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, multiple-columns

I have 2 dataframes:

```
camera = pd.DataFrame({'camera_sn':[23,34,465,987], 
                       'sn_sensor':[987,976,543,np.nan], 
                       'colormask':['color', 'grey', 'none', 'grey'],
                       'id':[23,45,np.nan,np.nan]})

sensor = pd.DataFrame({'quality_mask':['A','A',np.nan,'B'],
                       'sensor_sn':[987,976,543,np.nan],
                       'featureMask':['color', 'grey', 'none', 'grey'],
                       'id':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I did join these dfs with index `sensor_sn` and `sn_sensor` (I cannot change the column names):

```
join_cs = camera.join(sensor.set_index('sensor_sn'), on='sn_sensor', how='left', 
                      lsuffix='_camera',rsuffix='_sensor')
join_cs.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) #there where some duplicates
```

I now have the problem, that for `sn_sensor=nan` I get multiple index duplicates with different `quality_masks` which where not deleted.

(I know this isn't the case here, but with my original it is, because the size should be (5132,69) but after joining it is (15928,69) and after cutting duplicates it is (6061,69))

```
index  camera_sn  sensor_sn  id_camera colormask  featureMask quality_mask id_sensor
0          23        987       23        color      color        A             nan
1          34        976       45        grey       grey         A             nan
2          465       543       nan       none       none         nan           nan
2          465       543       nan       none       color        nan           nan
3          987       nan       nan       grey       grey         B             nan
3          987       nan       nan       grey       none         B             nan
3          987       nan       nan       grey       color        A             nan
3          987       nan       nan       grey       grey         A             nan
```

I now need a function that goes through `df3=join_cs` and compares every value of the columns `featureMask` and `quality_mask` with the columns in `df2=sensor`, deleting every row with a missmatch (for either column). Leaving in the end:

```
index  camera_sn  sensor_sn  id_camera colormask  featureMask quality_mask id_sensor`
0          23        987       23        color      color        A             nan
1          34        976       45        grey       grey         A             nan
2          465       543       nan       none       none         nan           nan
3          987       nan       nan       grey       grey         B             nan
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem well. You should be able to achieve the desidered result by performing an inner join between `join_cs` and `sensor` DataFrames considering the columns `[sensor_sn, featureMask, quality_mask]` as follows:

```
join_cs = pd.merge(join_cs, sensor, on=["sensor_sn", 'featureMask', 'quality_mask'])[join_cs.columns]
```

In this way, if there is a mismatch on one of these columns between `join_cs` and `sensor`, the responsible row will be discarded.

Comment: The problem is that sensor_sn is sn_sensor in join (I misstyped above) so I left it out and it gave me the KeyError: "[ *giving all remaining columns of sensor* ] not in Index"
So I added all column names in on=[...], no error but now my dataframe has the size (13736442,72), so it apparently added an enormous amount of rows and 2 columns...

Comment: It is not that clear to me. Could you add a minimal reproducible example of what is your problem and the desidered result? Because starting from the camera and sensor dataframes you posted and performing the join operation, the result is not what is illustrated in the penultimate table with 8 rows. It would be helpful if the example you provide has the error